# How to Approve, Reject,Complete the workflow through email(custom email template) in Alfresco Process Service

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I want to add 3 custom actions in the email notification.

I have created custom email template and integrated it with Alfresco process.
Also, I am able to send email to particular user, but I am not getting what link I should use in the template, so I can complete these actions.

Also, I am not getting taskId in the email template.

Please provide me some guidance, if ou have done with similar requirement.

Thanks, Deepak

Comment: the email template has been assigned on the user task? or you have a separate mail task?

Comment: @AbbasKararawala I need it for both scenarios. first has been assigned user task and the user will get notification for approve or reject, and in second scenario I have to send email in some time interval.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your "taskId" in process variable using a task Listener. providing name of variable corresponding to your task (which is to be referenced in the mail) and use it in your template using `${your_var}`.

Next part would be to create your custom endpoint which the user can call from the link in the email and complete the task.

A better option would be to send the user to the Task page (see the OOTB templates for more help).

Answer (score 1):

My [Alfresco Workflow Tutorial on ECM Architect](https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html) shows you exactly how to do this. It uses a custom web script that is invoked from a link in an email. The web script gets a reference to the workflow and then completes the task.